# Launcher Icons disappear

Tags: 12.04, boot, icons

Some Launcher icons disappear.
I locked them but they have disappeared again after boot.

I have Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS which I have installed today and updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go in tty1 by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, login with your usser name and password and run next commands:

```
unity --reset-icons
unity --reset
sudo reboot now
```

After reboot, the problem should disappear.