# Ubuntu 15.10 Launcher Icons Not Locking

Tags: launcher, unity-dash, 15.10

Just installed Ubuntu 15.10 x64 a couple of days back; *great by the way*.

Apps locked to the launcher are lost after every restart; regardless of whether they are pinned by selecting *Lock to Launcher* or dragged from **Dash**.

**How do I make them stick?**

Also, **Dash** seems to have some hiccups as well, freezing from time to time.

Comment: Default apps or the manually added ones?

Comment: The manually added ones. I've even created a **.desktop** entry for one in question.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/316050/icons-disappear - Does this help?

Comment: If you want any further details then comment and I will detail the above in an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it does not seem to work. I get this error: `Traceback ... File "/usr/bin/unity" ... Import glib ... ImportError: No module named glib`

Answer (score 1):

1. Install glib using the command:

> sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0

**EDIT:** Also, it seems that you might need to install python gst:

> sudo apt-get install python-gst*

1. Log out of your system.
2. Then press

> Ctrl + Alt + F1

3. Login with your Username & Password.
4. Then, run this commands

> unity --reset-icons
>
> unity --reset
>
> sudo reboot now

**EDIT:** If even still you are unable to lock items onto the launcher then, open Home then, press "Ctrl + h" to show hidden folders. Navigate to .config and move anything in the dconf folder to another directory(such as ~/dconf).

**EDIT:** Desktop file format:

> [Desktop Entry] Name=AppName
>
> Type=Application
>
> Exec=/path/to/App/App %f
>
> Terminal=false
>
> MimeType=application/x-app
>
> Icon=/path/to/App/App_icon.jpg
>
> Comment=App comment
>
> NoDisplay=false
>
> Categories=app_category;
>
> Name[en]=App

Comment: It seems that it's already installed, so the first **apt-get** function installed and updated nothing. Then I tried logging-off and performing the **Unity** resets, but with the same results.

Comment: @iSofia Edited, see if it works now.

Comment: I was able to install the **python** package, and then successfully reset **Unity**; but the apps are still not locking to the launcher. Same with manually installed apps and those installed by the **Software Center**.

Comment: @iSofia Edited.

Comment: I'd have to thank you for your tireless help. It appears that **Software Center** downloaded/installed apps are now able to be locked to the launcher. However, manually installed ones still don't; are there any setting that these must have in order to be locked? Perhaps I've done the **.desktop** file wrongly.

Comment: @iSofia Edited.

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't take either; lost after restart. I've exhaustively scoured and tried every available suggestion, but to no avail. The package in question was downloaded as a **.tar.gz.** file, extracted, and then the relevant **.desktop** and **.xml** files created and inserted as per instructions here: http://askubuntu.com/a/484218/469866. In any case, I'm grateful for your help, and thank you sincerely, Raphael.

Comment: I have similar problem creating a launcher item on unity for `ssvncviewer` app.  I can create the item on the launcher, but it won's show any running instance (one small triangle pointer per instance on the right or left side of the item).